# Adding points to a score

Tags: c#, math, console

Im building a console c# flash card game and I want to keep a score going to show at the end of how many where correct. I am thinking on what is the best course of action to do this I was thinking a for loop but it didn't work for me like I thought that it might and then again I am still new to programming so I am sure maybe I am just doing something wrong.

So, I have a double called answer.
and since I only need a single in I used another int that is called correctAnswer.
I was thinking I could use that to add to the for loop but it didn't go as planned 
so, I am just asking for what might be the best course of action to add points to a score. I also see another problem I will have by using answer as it will add a point even if they get it wrong but I can fix that once I get this sorted.

```
                    double answer = 0;
                    int correctAnswer = Convert.ToInt32(answer);

                    for (correctAnswer = 0; correctAnswer <= answer; correctAnswer++) ;

                    ///Setting up the switch statement
                    ///switch (variable)
                    ///      case 1:
                    ///      code;
                    ///      break;
                    ///      
                    switch (opSign)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            Console.WriteLine("What is the answer to " + num1 + (" Times " + num2 + " ?"));
                            answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                            if (answer == num1 * num2)
                            {

                                speechAnswers();
                                Console.WriteLine("You entered " + answer + " as the answer to " + num1 + " times " + num2 + "." + " You are correct good job! ");
                            }
                            else if (answer != num1 * num2)
                                Console.WriteLine("You are incorrect please try again");
                            break;
```

Comment: what is the use of your `correctAnswer` variable? why would u declare it to be the same as answer?

Answer (score 1):

This your the code after adding a small bit of code. Every time he answers correctly, Answer is incremented by 1. If you want to reset your score, You will need to make a function for that that happens when maybe, score decreases three times in a streak. This is your game.

```
           double answer = 0;
           int correctAnswer = Convert.ToInt32(answer);

                  for (correctAnswer = 0; correctAnswer <= answer; correctAnswer++) ;

                    ///Setting up the switch statement
                    ///switch (variable)
                    ///      case 1:
                    ///      code;
                    ///      break;
                    ///      
                    switch (opSign)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            Console.WriteLine("What is the answer to " + num1 + (" Times " + num2 + " ?"));
                            answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                            if (answer == num1 * num2)
                            {

                                speechAnswers();
                                Console.WriteLine("You entered " + answer + " as the answer to " + num1 + " times " + num2 + "." + " You are correct good job! ");
                                score += 1; // every time the answer is correct, score is incremented by 1.
                            }
                            else if (answer != num1 * num2)
                                Console.WriteLine("You are incorrect please try again");
                         // what happens on loss
                            break;
```

every time you write a code happens when the answer is correct, Add this
`score += 1;`